# Preventing sprites with random positions from overlapping in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am generating random sprites on a scene with random positions like so:

```
-(void)addWRight
{
int randNo = arc4random()%5;
int randType = arc4random()%3;

for(int i = 0; i <= randNo; i++)
{
    NSString *strSprite = @"1.png";
    if(randType == 0)
    {
        strSprite = @"1.png";
    }
    else if(randType == 1)
    {
        strSprite = @"2.png";
    }
    else
    {
        strSprite = @"3.png";
    }

    int minX = 130; 
    int maxX = 240; 
    int randX = arc4random() % (maxX - minX) + minX;

    CCSprite *spr = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:strSprite];
    spr.position = ccp(randX, 200);
    [self addChild:spr];
    [whiteArray addObject:spr];
}}
```

I add the sprites depending on the result of randNo. So if for example randNo value is 2 then, 3 sprites would be added. My problem is, on the random x-axis position of the sprite. I made it so that they are positioned anywhere between 130 - 240. This works however, since the x-axis is randomized, there's a tendency wherein two or more sprite would overlap with each other. So my question now is, how can I prevent the sprites from overlapping?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two approaches:

1. collision detection: before adding a new sprite, check that its bounds do not intersect with any other existing sprites';

in order to reduce the complexity of checking whether two bounds collide, you could do following:

1. discretize your space: define a grid; then assign random coordinates to your sprite within this grid; calculate the coordinates of the assigned grid cell in your whole space. E.g., imagine that your sprite is 20x40 and your space 320x480, then you could use a 16x12 grid; if you assign a sprite to cell (3,3), this would correspond to (60,120). In this case, you would detect the collision between two sprites by only comparing their coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

There is a code snippet posted by **timTheMystic** in [this](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/avoid-from-overlapping-sprites/) post. Although not a good, but still an acceptable solution to prevent overlaps between sprites.